# Writing from a large list to a text file in Python

Tags: python

Something strange happens when I try to write from a ordinary list, containing 648470 string-values, to a text file.

```
    textFile = open('bins.txt', 'w')

    for item in bigList:
        print item # This prints fine
        textFile.write(item)

    textFile.close()
```

The text file grows rapidly in file size and is filled with all kind of symbols, not the intended ones... Even if I just write a small span of the content of bigList the text file gets corrupted. If I do the exact same thing with a much smaller list, there's no problem.
Is the large size of the list causing this problem? The output of `print(bigList[:10])` is

```
['167', '14444', '118', '22110', '118', '8134', '82', '8949', '7875', '171']
```

Comment: Please show the part where you open the file.

Comment: @Smajjk Are you opening the file like `textFile = open(path, 'w')`? And are you sure you are writing text, and not numbers into each line?

Comment: I forgot to mention, an extract from the list would be good too - as given by Python if you do `print(bigList[:20])`, for example.

Comment: Note that your code as posted will not print the last item in `biglist`, because `range` does not include its ending number.  Instead use `range(biglist)` or even better rewrite the loop as `for item in biglist: textFile.write(item)`.  This won't solve your issue but your code will be more Pythonic.  My guess is that you have some sort of encoding issue.  Showing us some of the data as Lattyware suggests will be helpful.

Comment: I notice you're opening this was `'a'`, not `'w'`. What was in the file before? And—not to be patronizing, but I've made this kind of mistake before—are you sure you're looking at the data you appended, rather than the garbage that was already there? In fact, are you sure you appended anything at all (since you don't `close` the file, it may never flush the buffer to disk)?

Comment: What program do you use to view the file? The file consists of one extremely long line; perhaps that triggers a bug in the program. Try another way of viewing the file.

Comment: Seems this were the problem, writing to much to a single line... Works as it should now!

Answer (score 1):

It works absolutely fine to me.

In your code you are forgetting to close the file, and also, since you open the file in append mode, my guess is that you have some garbage in the file that was there and you forgot to remove.

Also, keep in mind that the write in that way will not separate the numbers in any way.

Comment: I changed from append mode to write mode and also closes the file. When I write using textFile.write(item) I do still not get the long line of numbers I am expecting but a mess of symbols, looks almost like there are written on top of eachother! But when I use   writeFile.write("%s\n" % item) it works?!

Comment: What version of python and OS are you using?

Comment: xubuntu 12.10 and Python 2.7.3

Comment: Are you sure the list only contains string objects?

Comment: try this to check:
reduce(lambda x,y: x and y, [isinstance(i,str) for i in bigList])

Comment: Can you try deleting the file?

Comment: I really have no clue at this point. Could you post the entire program on pastebin?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the file is having problems writing because some of the list objects are not strings. Try:

```
textFile = open('bins.txt', 'w')

for item in bigList:
    print item # This prints fine
    textFile.write(str(item))

textFile.close()
```

However I cannot see your list so I do not know for certain if this is an actual problem.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure why this wouldn't write then... It's odd.